# PySide error: not able to link QtCore

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyside

I am getting the below error when trying to run my pyside program:
When I try to use pip to reinstall PySide, I get the below error:

**
      Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "myfirstpython.py", line 3, in <module>
    from PySide.QtCore import Qt

  ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PySide/QtCore.so, 2): Symbol not found: __PyTrash_thread_deposit_object

  Referenced from: /usr/lib/libshiboken-python2.7.1.2.dylib

  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/lib/libshiboken-python2.7.1.2.dylib**
```

When I try to check my `PySide.__version__` it gives me a segmentation fault:11

I have checked several solutions available online but none seems to be working here.
:

```
Collecting PySide
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PySide (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for PySide
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
```

Comment: Which SO are you using? On Windows you can use this prebuilt wheel: [link](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyside)

Comment: This is OS X @MassimoFuccillo.

Comment: I have Yosemite.. do you think it could be incompatible??

Comment: Possibly. I believe I had it work on Yosemite, but using Yosemite caused me to ditch my OS X computer and install Linux, so...
I would try a brew install (if you have homebrew) or Macports (sudo port install py27-pyside)

Comment: I ran "sudo port install py27-pyside" and it seems to have installed everything successfully. Still I am getting the following error:        Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myfirstpython.py", line 3, in <module>
    from PySide.QtCore import Qt
ImportError: No module named PySide.QtCore

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS X, due to difficulties in compiling, don't try to use a PIP installation and try the pre-built binaries from here:

http://wiki.qt.io/PySide_Binaries_MacOSX

It has been confirmed to work for Mavericks.

You can also use brew or Macports, but I would not rely on pip:
http://pythoncentral.io/install-pyside-pyqt-on-windows-mac-linux/

Comment: I had installed using these very same binaries, it was working initially. Later, it started crashing with the above error. I am not even able to check the version number now.

Comment: Is Qt4.8 installed locally? Have you tried a Homebrew install?